# Protection website against cURL?

Tags: php, security, curl

By curiosity i've tried to parse html

```
$url = "http://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/Pages/subcategory.aspx?cat=Bebidas_Vinhos";

$agent= 'Googlebot-Image/1.0 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

from shop supermarket website and i get this message

> Error
>   This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information.
>   The incident ID is: N/A.

I found it strange and they have some protection against this type of "attacks", but how they protect this website and how they let google bot crawl for digital marketing purpose?

Comment: Easiest is simply to have a <noscript> tag in the supermarket's page to display that message, and use js to populate the rest of the page content for those accessing the page using a web browser.... curl can't handle javascript

Comment: the `curl` request works fine for me

Comment: I think my question is legitimate. Not even checked you if your answer is valid or not. In chrome, i turn off javascript and check the url in script. The website, shows every products, without image, but information is there. Thanks for the negative mark.

Comment: Alex Andrei, it's strange. Right now, i've tried to curl, from another internet connection (other ip) and the message is the same.

Comment: An alternative would be for the page to use a header redirect.... and you've not set your curl request to follow redirects.... `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: Mark Baker, that's it! Thanks.Can you put your answer, to mark it as right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try with session cookies, but this page not have content because is loaded async with ajax.

```
curl 'http://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/Pages/subcategory.aspx?cat=Bebidas_Vinhos' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: searchRefiner=%7B%22%22%3A%7B%221449049672079%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D; SPSessionGuid=ec3e4a3e-7cfe-4c8a-902f-1c64ba0868f4; __CommerceAnonymousShopper_ef77e72d-62b9-4b0f-8113-d111c9d6d7ce_Internet=0244rfNRN5rPgC7kvXzyqrNQg==WBGr/AUg99sKnXpF3QH4Sa5cHPFred5bJqPiwbFvDnL1jHUk6v0Jb0dpOZLY66bXpC8faWF7k5aOMi/qIkOgA4RNWuskMnicr6OJ12BBs8ns68kXmckzTJvkVEfDQB7DApeN5ULier028VPSLkChmWvBHyCHno328U6SrLu65m5e3lu521PF940napZPZIvN7hP51Yfi9c+FkwjIAZ+j8w==; MSCSProfile=287001FD2674671C70ED37E496ED003312D0DA42BDDB218BA1D2B71AD462488CF83AD1F7530553A13FDD4C8DB0E26123D3A02CCFBA6DAE49B72A185609583B9617878CEA5D73023FE7A74384436D54761511ED87FFA2AF58124E143C0E90DC9C72D55A51B3AE6EAB71153682F607FE3C29538E729117E4DD3D6B05C06E7FBA47; cPrompt_useCookies=1; cpup=2; _ga=GA1.2.532033017.1449049672; _dc_gtm_UA-158387-26=1; byside_webcare_tuid=5110f1jvvitrsyi82c2q4kddcxlrl0vdwfmrmtzeah679ditkl; __atuvc=1%7C48; __atuvs=565ebe4c6d710bda000; CampaignHistory=146148' -H 'Host: www.continente.pt' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0'
```

Comment: Strange, because with javascript turned off, i can get products (with no image) but with all other informations. I'll test.